# Unable to create dashboard for avg response time for azure function app

Tags: azure, logging

Iam not getting correct query for function app to average response time

Need azure log query

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: Can u provide sample query to find out 4xx errors query please

Comment: Community can provide the answer when you provide a query which you have tried and not getting result, the question needs to be programmatic in Stackoverflow, to make this look like that add a query

Comment: Hi Rithvik I need for http error query can help me here is my sample iam pasting

Comment: // Http 4XX count

2 // Show a column chart of the number of the logs containing 4xx in the last hour, per application.

3 AzureMetrics

4 | where Time Generated > ago (30d)

5 where MetricName in ("Http4xx") 6 | where_ResourceId contains "avt-prd" 7 | where Resource contains "func"

8 summarize 4XX_count = count() by bin (TimeGenerated, 1d), MetricName

render timechart

Comment: With above query it showing wrong but when I have checked in function app we don’t have any error for http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Iam not getting correct query for function app to average response time

To get the response time of Function apps, you can use below query:

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == 'rithwik21'
```

[image]

To get the average response time of Function apps, you can use below query:

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == 'rithwik21'
| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
```

[image]

```
 requests
    | where cloud_RoleName == 'rithwik21'
    | summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
    | project avg_duration
```

[image]

Here **rithwik21** is the functionapp name.

To find out any error you can use below query:

```
traces
| where message conatins "type error message"
```

Comment: Hi tried with about traces query but not getting results can u pls help me for 4xx and 5xx error query